# Non-symmmetric generalization of Gaussian integral.

Tags: gaussian-integral, superalgebra

Suppose that $A$ is a symmetric, positive definite $n \times n$ matrix.
Then we have the relation
\begin{align*}
\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \exp( - \frac{1}{2} A_{ij} x_j x_i) dx_1 \dots d x_n  =  \sqrt{ \text{Det} (2\pi A^{-1})} 
\end{align*}
Does this formula have an extension if $A$ is not symmetric?

Comment: $A$ has to be not just symmetric but positive definite, otherwise the integral diverges, as it would when it is non-symmetric.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited.

Comment: Since what you have in the exponent is a quadratic form you can replace $A$ with its symmetrization $A_s=\frac12(A+A^T)$ without changing the integral. If $A_s$ happens to be positive definite the formula holds with $A$ replaced by $A_s$ on the right.

Comment: Okay, but this assumes that the entries in $A$ are real?

Comment: No, it doesn't. So Conifold has answered your question. Also the (superalgebra) tag appears irrelevant.